# Is Matsutarou imitating a famous Japanese enka singer?

Tags: matsutarou

In the opening song matsutarou sings along with Reika. They're both dressed in traditional kimono.

[image]

Matsutarou has these weird pink things on  the side of his head though. The only thing I can think of is that he's impersonating someone and it's possibly an imitation of that singer's hair? That doesn't really explain why it is pink though.

Does anyone know what the pink strands are?